# FPDF weirdly error put image in CELL

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, fpdf

i have no idea about this, why the image is out of the line

here's the result

[image]

here's my codes

```
        $fpdf->Cell(65,30,$fpdf->Image('assets/images/qrcodes/qrcodse.png', $fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), 30),1,0,'',false);
            $fpdf->cell(10,30,'',0,0,'');
        $fpdf->Cell(65,30,$fpdf->Image('assets/images/qrcodes/qrcodse.png', $fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), 30),1,0,'',false);
            $fpdf->Ln(33);

        $fpdf->Cell(65,30,$fpdf->Image('assets/images/qrcodes/qrcodse.png', $fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), 30),1,0,'',false);
            $fpdf->cell(10,30,'',0,0,'');
        $fpdf->Cell(65,30,$fpdf->Image('assets/images/qrcodes/qrcodse.png', $fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), 30),1,0,'',false);
            $fpdf->Ln(33);

        $fpdf->Cell(65,30,$fpdf->Image('assets/images/qrcodes/qrcodse.png', $fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), 30),1,0,'',false);
            $fpdf->cell(10,30,'',0,0,'');
        $fpdf->Cell(65,30,$fpdf->Image('assets/images/qrcodes/qrcodse.png', $fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), 30),1,0,'',false);
            $fpdf->Ln(33);

        $fpdf->Cell(65,30,$fpdf->Image('assets/images/qrcodes/qrcodse.png', $fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), 30),1,0,'',false);
            $fpdf->cell(10,30,'',0,0,'');
        $fpdf->Cell(65,30,$fpdf->Image('assets/images/qrcodes/qrcodse.png', $fpdf->GetX(), $fpdf->GetY(), 30),1,0,'',false);
            $fpdf->Ln(33);
```

it's only looping the same CELL function

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cell()` method expects a string as its third parameter. While the `Image()` method does not return anything.

That writing: You cannot place an image into a cell this way. It does not do what you expect.

Just move the `Image()` calls before each `Cell()` call and you will see no difference.

The page break you see is triggered because the later `Cell()` call is triggering it. You may disable it or set another bottom margin value through the [`SetAutoPageBreak()`](http://%20http://fpdf.org/en/doc/setautopagebreak.htm) method:

```
$fpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
// or
$fpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);
```

If you disable it, you will need to add the pages yourself.

Comment: so i put the Image() calls before each Cell() as you said, and the result is the same
but now i set the SetAutoPageBreak to false and then i put the AddPage manually with condition in looping
and it is on! thanks...